# Read int started with a zero and store it into array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I wanna read a number and store it in a array,
for example,
Number: 0600
after being stored:

```
array[0] = 0,
array[1] = 6,
array[2] = 0,
array[3] = 0
```

these are my functions:

```
int main ()
{
    int comb[20];
    printf ("Combination: ");
    scanf ("%d", &seq);
    read_sequence (comb, seq);

//Just testing
    printf ("%d\n", comb[3]);
    printf ("%d\n", comb[2]);
    printf ("%d\n", comb[1]);
    printf ("%d\n", comb[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d ", comb[i]);
    }
}

int number_of_digits (int n)
{
    if (n < 10) return 1;
    if (n < 100) return 2;
    if (n < 1000) return 3;
    if (n < 10000) return 4;
    if (n < 100000) return 5;
    if (n < 1000000) return 6;
    if (n < 10000000) return 7;
    if (n < 100000000) return 8;
    if (n < 1000000000) return 9;
    return 10;
}

int power (int b, int a) // I don't want to use pow()
{
    int i = 0, result = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        result = result * b;
    }

    return result;
}

void read_sequence (int comb[], int seq)
{
    int n = 0, i = 0, k = 0;

    n = number_of_digits (seq);
    n = n - 1;

    for (i = n; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (i != n) comb[i] = (seq / power (10, k)) % 10;

        else if (i == n) comb[i] = (seq % 10);

        k++;
    }
}
```

The code works fine when using numbers that doesn't start with zeros, but for some reason that I can't see, it doesn't store the first zeros of my int into the array, this is what it shows:

Combination: 0900
1966227384
0
0
9
9 0 0 1966227384 6422252 1965910434

With other number:

Combination: 9876
6
7
8
9
9 8 7 6 6422252 1965910434

Can someone help me here?

Comment: In the moment you read the number with scanf, you lose the information how many zeroes preceded it. The cleanest option is probably to handle the data as string, not as integers

Comment: `scanf ("%s", array);`

Comment: in general, in C, a number that starts with a 0 is interpreted as an octal number rather than a decimal number

Comment: in the posted code, the variable: `seq` is not defined

Comment: the posted code is missing the prototypes for the sub functions

Comment: strongly suggest compiling with the `-g` parameter then using `gdb` to step through the code while inputting some number like `09` and display the values at each step.  The first thing you will notice is that scanf() when doing the conversion to `int`, drops the leading 0s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `scanf("%d", ...)` does not retain the textual input - only the numeric value.  Leading zeros are not "remembered".

Use `fgets()` to read the line and then parse it for digits.

```
#define N 20

int main (void) {
    int comb[N];
    printf ("Combination: ");
    char buf[N*2 + 2];  // use a generous read buffer
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
    char p = buf;
    if (*p == '-' || *p == '+') p++;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      if (*p < '0' || *p > '9') {
        break;
      }
      comb[i] = *p - '0';
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf ("%d ", comb[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

To find the number fo digits in an `int`, simply repeatedly divide by 10.

```
int number_of_digits(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  do {
    count++;
    n /= 10;
  } while (n);
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I was about to write nearly the same code.  One subtle bug - the above doesn't handle negative numbers.  I would recommend checking for `(buf[0] == '-')` and allowing it.   (And bonus points for handling the case where the next number after the `'-'` is not a digit.) And +1 the result in `number of digits` if `n < 0`  The biggest buffer you will need to read an integer can be expressed as `buf[sizeof(int)*4+1]`

Comment: @selbie Fair critique about `'-'`.  Code amended.

Comment: @selbie Disagree about `buf[sizeof(int)*4+1]`.  Consider when `CHAR_BIT` is much greater than 8.  I have found `10*sizeof(interger_type)*CHAR_BIT/33 + 3`to be effective.

Comment: I like that sizeof formula you suggest. It's more accurate and doesn't over allocate. But can you elaborate on what you mean by: *Consider when CHAR_BIT is much greater than 8* ?

Comment: @selbie Say if `CHAR_BIT==16`, and `int` was 32 bit: `sizeof(int)*4+1` --> `2*4+1` --> `9`, insufficient for -2,147,483,648 which needs size 12.

Comment: Persnickety typo, `char p = buff;` has one too many `f`'s in it... (for Leffler - you may remove the *ultimate* or *penultimate* `'f'` -- the choice is yours...)